# How to stop background overlay covering text and content

Tags: css, background, overlay

I am redesigning a website and am nearly done
However I have a slight problem regarding my background tile overlay:

```
http://176.32.230.4/mackenziefoy.com/mackenziefoy/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/tile.png/
```

At the moment it appears like this:

```
http://176.32.230.4/mackenziefoy.com/mackenziefoy/)
```

I would like it to ONLY cover the bg image:

```
http://176.32.230.4/mackenziefoy.com/mackenziefoy/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/background1.jpg/
```

Not over the text or navigation. I am a little stuck! I have seen it done well on other websites but can't seem to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overlaying semitransparent elements (`#title` has `opacity:0.35` for example), so it's all showing completely correctly. If you don't want a background to 'shine through', don't put a transparent element on top of it, just make it opaque and set the correct colors for the element itself. There is no other flexible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I know it can be achieved somehow as I saw it on this website:
http://www.aurumdesign.com/
Does anyone know how I can achieve the same effect?

Comment: They didn't apply any `opacity` to their overlays like you did, so their background doesn't shine through. They also added a semitransparent **background** to all text elements, which has an entirely different effect of making the entire **element** transparent with `opacity`. To see most easily how they did it, just spy - right click the element, and hit 'Inspect Element' (in Chrome or with Firebug in FF) to see the applied CSS rules.

Comment: Ok I see. Is there anyway to just make sure the text isn't transparent? Thanks

Comment: Don't use opacity on the container, replace it for example with `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);` to achieve pretty much what that other site does.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a semi-transparent .png image (solid black or pattern) background for the content and title divs this will make the same effect too without affecting the text